# What is the fourth number of PyAutoGUI's getpixel function (RGB+?)

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm a Python beginner.
According to PyAutoGUI's documentation[1](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html),
getpixel function returns a tuple of three numbers, (R,G,B) of course.
However, my code returns a tuple of four numbers.

```
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("imagefilename.png")
print(img.getpixel((10,10)))
```

Return value should be for example `(150, 210, 255)`, but in my case it was like `(0, 150, 210, 255)`. With some simple analysis, I got to know the latter three numbers are R, G, B, respectively. Then what is the first number? Or, is something wrong with my Python environment?

Here are some of real return values.

```
(0, 168, 229, 255)
(63, 222, 250, 255)
(247, 244, 246, 255)
(0, 167, 229, 255)
(0, 168, 229, 255)
(0, 167, 233, 255)
```

mac OS X Sierra(10.12.4), Python 3.6, the code above was run on bash.

Comment: transparency or alpha component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors can not only hold a RGB representation

[image]

there is too an RGB**A**

[image]

the Alpha component is just a value for the transparency
[image]

see in the image Lena behind a red circle(0xFF0000 ) alpha=0%
and Lena behind a transparent red circle(0xFF0000 ) alpha=60%

Comment: thank you for the information. I didn't have slightest idea of alpha channel.

Comment: is the transparency... a value between 0 and 100%

Comment: see the edited answer, and note how lena looks like behind transparent circles...

Comment: thank you for the information. I didn't have slightest idea of alpha channel.  (additional information for future visitors): The returned tuple was (alpha,R,G,B) when the Image object was created from png(as shown above) or screenshot(<- so this is different from what the documentation says),  while it was (R, G, B) when the Image object was created from jpg file.

Comment: @Yasushi.A if this answer your question, please accept the answer!