# Why does pyautogui get pixel returns 4 items

Tags: python, rgb, pyautogui, getpixel

I tried to use pyautogui to get a rgb of a pixel of a screen shot. And instead of returning an rgb, it returns 4 items. How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
import pyautogui

im1 = pyautogui.screenshot()
im1.save("/Users/barhibel/Desktop/TempFolder/scren.png")
print(im1.getpixel((100, 200)))
```

And here is what I get:

```
(248, 241, 227, 255)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the fourth number of PyAutoGUI's getpixel function (RGB+?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934073/what-is-the-fourth-number-of-pyautoguis-getpixel-function-rgb)

Comment: it is RGBA , A means opacity. ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24538774

Comment: You probably wanna try `print(pyautogui.pixel(100, 200))`